# Redirect a user from a webforms vb app page to a mvc app page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a vb .net webforms application and in one of the pages I have a link that I want to send to a page in a mvc project within my solution.

I've inherited the project in my webforms app but I have no idea where to go from there.

```
response.redirect("~/Home/Index")
```

that didn't work since the mvc application is not in the same project as the page where the link is.

Here's how the applications are set up

```
SomeApplication.sln
 - Applications (solution folder)
     App1 (project - vb .net webforms app)
 - Components (solution folder)
     App2 (project - c# mvc app)
```

In App1, I have a page with a link to go to a page in App2.

I need help. I tried searching for documentation to no avail.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, that you want to create a link in WebForms page to navigate to some MVC page, then - when you run the solution, can you navigate to desired MVC page in your browser (ie `localhost:xxxxx/home/index`)?
If that works, can't you just add an anchor element to your WebForms page with the address that works in the browser?

```
<a href="/home/index">To the MVC!</a>
```

Comment: No that doesn't work because the path to the MVC page isn't in the same path as the path to the Webforms. When I do that, the "physical path" it's looking for is C:\MyFolder\Branch\Applications\App1\Home\Index when the "physical path" is actually C:\MyFolder\Branch\Components\App2\Home\Index. Even if I put localhost:xxxxx/Components/App2/Home/Index it still doesn't work. Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: Oh, seeing your answer I didn't realise that what happens when you run the solution is that both projects (WebForms and MVC) are launched simultaneously on different ports - although it seems quite obvious now.

Comment: Good catch, glad you could solve it by yourself (don't forget to mark your answer as a correct one). Just to note something that you are probably well aware of - it is probably not a good idea to hardcode all the redirects with domain:port segment in them (since that will prob. be different once deployed), but instead pass it via variable - perhaps as an appSetting value from web.config, ie.: `response.redirect(ConfigutaionManager.AppSettings["MvcDomain"] + "/home/index)`.

Answer (score 0):

Found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446539/redirecting-from-asp-net-webforms-to-mvc?rq=1), which I hadn't seen before in my searches and it got me thinking. When running the app, I decided to have a look at the IIS ports that are running. We also have a web service and that runs on a different port. That's when I noticed that the MVC app (App2) was running as well... on a third port. So... instead of doing the `response.redirect("localhost:11111/home/index)` (port for webforms App1), I did a `response.redirect("localhost:22222/home/index)` (port for App2) and that worked.